# How to first split the string and then use the get Substring in robot framework

Tags: split, substring, robotframework

I am new to robot framework
I am getting a paragraph from a page which has text like
"This will be the reference number no1234567899. A confirmation email will be sent.

The text is not constant and keeps varying.

I want to fetch only 1234567899
so I tried to use split string

```
@{realNumber} =  split string    ${number}   no
log to console    ${realNumber}[1]
${refNumber}   ${realNumber}[1]
log to console    get substring    ${refNumber}    0   9
```

But when I use the above code, it is giving me error as
No keyword with name '${realNumber}[1]' found.

How do i just fetch the number, as the rest of the text is not constant?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error comes from this line:

```
${refNumber}   ${realNumber}[1]
```

, which you probably meant as assignment. That's one way to do it:

```
${refNumber}   Set Variable    ${realNumber}[1]
```

Once you've done that, the value of `${realNumber}[1]` will probably be the number you're after, plus any string afterwards.
Using a regexp should be more suitable for the task; here's a sample with a group matching digits after the string "no":

```
${refNumber}   Get Regexp Matches    ${number}     no(\\d+)    1
```

The keyword is in the "String" library, and the returned value is a list - you'll probably want the first member (if there is a match).